# Which is correct "I run very quickly" or "I run very fast"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

> I run very quickly.

Can I use the word "quickly" or do I have to change it to "fast?".

Comment: [An odd Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ran+very+quickly%2Cran+very+fast%2Cran+quickly%2Cran+fast&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cran%20very%20quickly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cran%20very%20fast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cran%20quickly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cran%20fast%3B%2Cc0) where preference inverts with or without "very"

Answer (score 2):

Native English speakers are more likely to use *fast* in that sentence, but *quickly* wouldn't be wrong.

While *fast* and *quickly* are usually interchangeable, *fast* is generally used more often talking about actual speed (km/hr), while *quickly* is used more often when talking about how much time it takes to do something.

So we are likely to use *quickly* in the sentence

> When Tom spotted the tiger in the distance, he ran back to his car very quickly,

and *fast* in the sentence

> Tom has a good chance of winning the race because he can run very fast.

But if you interchanged *fast* and *quickly* in the above sentences, you wouldn't be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See some examples about that here. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/fast-quick-or-quickly

Fast seems to be the better word for "run fast" as [JavaLatte mentions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/291959/139882)

Comment: I think that's an over-simplification, other things being equal. According to the Cambridge Dictionary, fast is rated as A1 as an adjective and A2 as an adverb in British English. I would be more inclined to say "we were running fast" than to say "we were running quickly", and that's definitely and adverbal use. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quickly

Comment: According to [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+fast&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), 'run fast' doesn't seem to be much less common in British than in American English.

Comment: Yeah, and that's certainly a better reference than mine. See here too: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/fast-quick-or-quickly I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use quickly in your sentence, but according to this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run%20fast%2Crun%20quickly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crun%20fast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crun%20quickly%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crun%20fast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crun%20quickly%3B%2Cc0), fast is used a lot more frequently with the verb "run".